# Función strcat en C++

Tags: c++

Buenas, os cuento mi situación.

En C++ existen librerías,  o  que te hacen la función de strlen para medir la longitud de esa string. Yo lo que he hecho es recrear esa función para utilizarla de este modo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned int strlen(char *p){
unsigned int i;
for( i=0; p[i] != 0; i++){
}   return i;
}

int main(){

char unaFrase[100] = "¡Hola Mundo!";
unsigned int f = strlen(&naFrase[0]);

cout << "El string " << unaFrase << " contiene " << f << "caracteres.\n";
}
```

Bien pues ahora quiero hacer lo mismo con la función strcat, que lo que hace es concatenar dos strings.
Lo estoy haciendo de tal modo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void strcat(char *pS, char *pD, char *pF){

foir int i = 0; pS[i] != 0; i++){

for(int i=0; pS != 0 && pD != 0; i++){

pF[i] = pS[i] + pD[i];
    }
}

int main(){

char primeraFrase[100] = "Hola, me llamo Gustavo.";
char segundaFrase[100] = " Encantado de conocerte.";
char resultado[300];

strcat(&primeraFrase[0], &segundaFrase[0], &resultado[0]);

cout << resultado << endl;

}
```

Vale, pues me compila pero al ejecutarlo me salen resultados aleatorios.
Espero que haya quedado claro lo que estoy intentando hacer, si no es así intentaré explicarme mejor.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, en realidad lo que estás haciendo es sumar valores de caracteres en ascii. La solución adecuada sería copiar a la cadena resultado primero la cadena 1 y luego la 2. Algo así:

```
void strcat(char *pS, char *pD, char *pF){
  int i = 0;
  for (; pS[i] != 0; i++){
    pF[i] = pS[i];
  }

  int j = 0;
  for (; pD[j] != 0; j++){
    pF[i+j] = pD[j];
  }

  pF[j]=0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviando que la indentación de tu código dificulta el análisis del mismo, que tienes errores de sintaxis y que faltan llaves de cierre, tienes dos problemas en tu función de concatenado:

#### Ocultación de variables ([Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)).

Como variable de control en tus bucles estás usando dos variables diferentes con el mismo nombre: `i`, en el momento de usar la variable usas la más interna:

```
void strcat(char *pS, char *pD, char *pF){
//           v <-- primera variable 'i'
    for (int i = 0; pS[i] != 0; i++){
//               v <-- segunda variable 'i'
        for (int i=0; pS != 0 && pD != 0; i++){
            pF[i] = pS[i] + pD[i];
//            ~~~     ~~~     ~~~ <-- todas las 'i' de esta linea son la segunda
        }
    }
}
```

#### Suma de valores.

Tu segundo problema es que no estás concatenando nada, guardas en el arreglo `pF`, en la misma posición, la suma de `pS` y `pD`; por ejemplo, en la primera vuelta sumas `H` (valor 72) y `E` (valor 69) y lo guardas en `pF` (guardas 141).

#### Propuesta.

Usa un puntero a la cadena de destino para copiar la primera frase y, sin modificar dicho puntero, úsalo para continuar copiando la segunda frase:

```
void strcat(char *pS, char *pD, char *pF)
{
    auto destino = pS;
    for (; *pD; ++pD, ++destino) *destino = *pD;
    for (; *pF; ++pF, ++destino) *destino = *pF;
}
```